# Why does delete statement to a table, lock a select statement to the same table -- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I have an application written in Spring 3.0 and uses SQL Server 2012 Enterprise as RDS.

I have been using `@Transactional` on my DAO operations and in this particular case

```
    @Transactional
    public void removeAll(String token) {

        cacheDao.delete(token);

    }

    public ClassSome getValue(String id) {
        return cacheDao.getValue(id);
    }
```

My delete operations are transactional but select operations are unspecified. Is that the reason why deadlock occurs below?

Lately I have been experiencing deadlocks in database. Mainly these two operations above gets deadlocks.

I don't understand how can queries on one single table deadlocks each other. Here is a sample deadlock list DBA's have given me:

```
<deadlock-list>
<deadlock victim="process1180f5d498">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process1180f5d498" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:1266103551:0 " waittime="2141" ownerId="1748561" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.140" XDES="0x117ce7ba40" lockMode="S" schedulerid="30" kpid="4424" status="suspended" spid="87" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.140" lastbatchcompleted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.137" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.137" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="xxxx" hostpid="0" loginname="xxxx" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1748561" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="74" sqlhandle="0x02000000e0a92205aebcb9dd3f38539312f56b0c41af55990000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
select token, type, value from cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 varchar(8000),@P1 varchar(8000))select token, type, value from cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1                    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process117d375c38" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:1266103551:29 " waittime="2141" ownerId="1748560" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.140" XDES="0xf68c743a8" lockMode="X" schedulerid="64" kpid="9628" status="suspended" spid="96" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.140" lastbatchcompleted="2013-12-25T11:24:17.140" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.140" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="xxxx" hostpid="0" loginname="xxx" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1748560" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="74" sqlhandle="0x0200000023b477359eec278e4060e11f3a1c194cbed41cc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
delete cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 varchar(8000),@P1 varchar(8000))delete cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1                    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1266103551" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname="xxxx.dbo.cache" id="lock10034ef580" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1266103551">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process117d375c38" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1180f5d498" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="29" objid="1266103551" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname="xxxx.dbo.cache" id="lock1011729e00" mode="IS" associatedObjectId="1266103551">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1180f5d498" mode="IS"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process117d375c38" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

EDIT #1

```
-- Results for: 
    SELECT  i.name, i.allow_row_locks, i.allow_page_locks
    FROM    sys.indexes i
    WHERE   i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cache')

name    allow_row_locks allow_page_locks
NULL    1   1
IND_cache_token_type    1   1
```

Comment: Look into snapshot isolation. This is a common countermeasure for fixing locking problems with SELECT's.

Comment: @usr: Please stop giving incomplete suggestions. And why SI and not RCSI ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean not sure what you're referring to. I do not have time to give a complete answer for this question. That's why I recommend to *look into* this topic. I do not recommend just turning it on. If you want to, I'll chat with you to discuss this.

Comment: @usr: please see my answer, note #3.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I did see that and I upvoted it. For read-only transactions SI *is* pretty much a simple decision, though. It just takes readers out of the picture with regards to locking and blocking. I wouldn't dismiss it on the basis that it *might* be unsuitable. It is likely to be suitable, but must be understood and tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Most likely, the cause of this DL is a missing index. Try to create following index:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IX_Cache_Token_Type
ON dbo.Cache (Token, Type)
INCLUDE (Value)
```

This index should help both type of queries:

```
select token, type, value from cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1
```

and

```
delete cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1
```

2) If this index doesn't eliminate these DLs then should ask yourself why two concurrent transactions try to delete / read the same row ?

3) Switching to Snapshot Isolation isn't a simple decision:

- [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity (part 1)?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/21/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-1.aspx)
- [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity (part 2)?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/26/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-2.aspx)
- [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity (part 3)?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/08/25/snapshot-isolation-a-threat-for-integrity-part-3.aspx)
- [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity (part 4)?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/09/15/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-4.aspx)

**Edit #1:**

```
DECLARE @sqlhandle1 VARBINARY(64);
SET @sqlhandle1 = 0x02000000e0a92205aebcb9dd3f38539312f56b0c41af55990000000000000000000000000000000000000000
SELECT  qp.query_plan
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(@sqlhandle1) qp

DECLARE @sqlhandle2 VARBINARY(64);
SET @sqlhandle2 = 0x0200000023b477359eec278e4060e11f3a1c194cbed41cc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
SELECT  qp.query_plan
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(@sqlhandle2) qp
```

**Edit #2:**
Also we need to check if row / page locks are allowed:

```
SELECT  i.name, i.allow_row_locks, i.allow_page_locks
FROM    sys.indexes i
WHERE   i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cache')
```

Comment: because in some way, updates to this cache table is implemented using delete first insert second.

Comment: @LostMohican: this still  can't explains why Select tries to read a deleted row/updated row. You need to add more info. Do you have insert/delete triggers on cache table?

Comment: @LostMohican: Can you tell me what results returns following query: `SELECT t.lock_escalation_desc FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cache')` ? Auto or Table ?

Comment: It returned table. What does it mean?

Comment: @LostMohican: [The lock escalation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx) is made at table level and not at partition level. Lock escalation is one of typical causes of deadlocks.

Comment: by the way we have the first index on two columns you mentioned

Comment: @LostMohican: That index INCLUDEs http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(v=sql.90).aspx also the column value?

Comment: @LostMohican: [1] Also, I need an answer for the question from #2. [2] And at this point I need the execution plans for these queries. See Edit #1. I need that query plans in XML format. [3] And I need also the output from Edit #2.

Comment: no we didnt include value column on the index, so it says it puts the column to leaf level, how does it benefit the query? i will also answer your other questions

Comment: I dont think that a delete and a select of the same token and type is being queried on table. Actually there must be only one thread working on one token. How can we prove that a delete and a select for the same token is sent to server?

Comment: Query at edit#1 returned empty. I added the results for #2 at my post as edit.

Comment: @LostMohican: index + `value` `INCLUDE`[d]/covering  column: the select query (`select token, type, value from cache where token=@P0 and type=@P1`) will benefit from index because the `SELECT` clause must return the values from 3 columns: `token, type` and `value`. Because your index `IND_cache_token_type` has only two column (`token` and `type`) SQL Server has two options: [1] it use a Index Seek on IND_cache_token_type + RID Lookup (to read from HEAP table the values of `value` column) or [2] it uses a Table Scan to filter and return required values.

Comment: + My index will help SQL Server to Seek and return all values without the need of a RID Lookup (for `value`).

Comment: "Query at edit#1 returned empty." + the output of my query **Edit #2**: I're you sure you have executed this queries on the same server and DB ? *Maybe* you have got deadlocks on a production server but you have executed these queries on a dev/test database server! For example, the output of `SELECT ... FROM sys.indexes i ...` shows that `dbo.cache` table is a HEAP table but the XML deadlock graph demonstrate that the same table is partitioned. And this means you have a clustered index on `dbo.cache` table.

Comment: + These two things are a contradiction because a SQL Server table can't be Heap **and** Clustered Index.

Comment: Yes I dont have access to production table but I will send this query to DBA team.

Answer (score 4):

Consider we have these tables:

```
Department (department-id (pk) , name);
Emp (EMP_ID (pk), department-id (FK), name);
```

When deleting a row from department, to maintain integrity RDMBS have to search and find all child records in `Emp` table.

When there is no index on the `department-id` column in `Emp` table, a full table scan will occur on `Emp`, RDBMS will lock entire `Emp` table before the operation.

If `Emp` has many records the operation will take a long time, in the mean time if other transaction(s) trying to manipulate `Emp`, timeout or deadlocks may happen.

It is highly recommended to create indexes on foreign keys to prevent the problem.

More information is needed to investigate your problem, I just mentioned a common problem.

Comment: Hi, poor architecture design may result in dead looks, like nested or two face commits that have poorly exception handling. Another reason will be If you are using ORM frameworks, some unnoticed updates may happen when domain data is noticed dirty by ORM. Trace the scenario and see what SQL is running on the process.